# Angular 4 http service 2 requests made to API

Tags: angular, http, xmlhttprequest, angular-http

I am making requests from my Angular 4 client app to my remote API, with custom headers. In network tab, I notice 2 requests made each time, one with Request Method Options and the other one with Post/Put/Get.

http://prntscr.com/gtiqwz

http://prntscr.com/gtir2z

http://prntscr.com/gtir8z

Is this supposed to be happening? Thanks.

Comment: It's normal. You browser makes a CORS preflight request to make sure the back-end server your are requesting allows such operations (Post/Put/Get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. browser makes 2 requests

1. OPTIONS
2. GET/POST/PUT/DELETE (Whichever your request is)

OPTIONS request is to check if the SERVER on which you are making request allows request operations i.e. GET/POST/PUT/DELETE (Whichever your request is).

These are defined at server at as  e.x.`'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST'`.

If the requested method is not allowed then only OPTIONS request will be called with an error.